# unable to succesfully run xlwings addin

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

Dear Stackoverflow members

I've been trying to install and use the xlwings addin for several days now but I am not able to get it running... I really would like to use xlwings, but it is being painfully difficult.

I am using Anaconda.

xwlings is installed and works perfectly (I can read/write from/to an .xlsx file) but what I want to really do is to call python functions from excel and for that I need the addin.

The docs are not super useful here and I've tried to follow this guide (from https://newtonexcelbach.com/2017/07/30/installing-xlwings-0-11-4/):

" Run xlwings addin install from a command prompt. Reopen Excel and check if the xlwings Ribbon appears. If not, copy xlwings.xlam (from your xlwings installation folder under addin\xlwings.xlam manually into the XLSTART folder. You can find the location of this folder under Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings… > Trusted Locations, under the description Excel default location: User StartUp. Restart Excel and you should see the add-in"

When I opened excel I did not see the addin. I put the xlwings .xlam file into the XLSTAR folder... reopened excel and the addin was still not there. Then I put the .xlam file also in this folder : "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns". 
The .xlam file is now in both folders, and now I can see the xlwings addin.

then I create a folder with myproject.xlsm and myproject.py files by running "xlwings quickstart myproject" from the anaconda promt. The  files are there but then when I try to call any python function/Script from the vba modules I always get this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\joanc\myproject\myproject.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'"
```

for example, I get this error when I try to run the code that is already available when myproject.xlsm is created. The code looks like this:

```
sub SampleCall()
    mymodule=Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".",-1, vbTextCompare)
    RunPython("import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule ".hello_xlwings()")
end sub
```

I tried to run this code directly from the developer tab and also from a button created in sheet1 and assigning its corresponding macro...

As a side note if I go to the developer tab>tools>references i can see the xlwings checkbox active... so this should not be a problem.

Well, this is all I've done so far... no idea what I am doing wrong and what to do next. I would really like to use this package but if anyone knows a good alternative I am totally open (not only to read/write from/to excel but also to call python scripts/functions directly from excel)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I've downloaded the Montecarlo example from the website... when I try to run it I get the following error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\joanc\desktop\montecarlo\simulation.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'". So it looks like excel is connecting to the python script but does not found the modules... maybe this helps to solve the problem

Comment: Also, I've removed the *.xlam file from ...\Microsoft\AddIns folder. I still can see the addin in the ribbon... so now, the .*xlam folder is just installed in the XLSTART folder.